# XmlSerialization and interfaces

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, serialization, interface

I know that you can't serialize/deserialize using an interface but I'm confused by behaviour I'm seeing.

When I deserialize and cast back to the interface, some properties are null. But if I cast back to the concrete type the same property has a value?

So, given this XML (shortened for brevity):

```
<Page>
  <ComponentPresentations>
    <ComponentPresentation>
      <Component>
        <Categories>
          <Category>
            <Id>tcm:35-540-512</Id>
```

Deserializing with

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Page));
page = (IPage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

page.ComponentPresentations[0].Component.Categories <-- is null
```

But if I cast back to the type,

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Page));
page = (Page)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

page.ComponentPresentations[0].Component.Categories <-- is not null!
```

The Page type exposes the interface Categories property and a non-interface property - I assume to get around the serializing interface problem.

```
public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
[XmlIgnore]
IList<ICategory> IComponent.Categories
{
    get { return Categories as IList<ICategory>; }
}
```

Is this because the interface property doesn't expose a setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The problem is **Contravariance** not being supported by `List<T>` and `IList<T>`. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) is a good reference.

---

Have a look at this simple code:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{

}

public class MyImplementation : IMyInterface
{

}

List<MyImplementation> myImplementations = new List<MyImplementation>();
Console.WriteLine(myImplementations as IList<IMyInterface> == null); // OUTPUT: true!!
```

So as you can see, `Categories as IList<ICategory>` will always be null. While `Categories as IList<Category>` will be OK.

**Nothing to do with serialisation**.

Comment: @Neil using `IEnumerable<T>` will give you the feature you need.